# Does my panel with a separate disconnect need an isolated neutral bus?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, neutral

Sorry about lack of language ....just need a little guidance!

After a fire I had to install new meter below which I installed a small exterior breaker box . Here I can switch all power off to the new breaker panel inside. There is a 100 amp breaker in the outside box below the meter and both neutral and ground are on the same bus there.

There is no ground bus in the new consumer box ....just two neutral buses running either side . Can I wire in both neutral and ground to same bus or will I need to create separate bus for ground leading back to outside shut off box ?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to isolate the neutral bus from the ground bus in the new panel. These are usually a separate item and can be found in most hardware stores. Do not bond the neutral busses in the new panel.

Good Luck

Comment: Ok so if i separate one of the neutral buss bars from the bridge in the new indoor box  I should be able to us it as a ground that connects directly back to outside box neutral/ground bus

Comment: Yes but you need to bond the one you are using for the grounds not the neutral.

Comment: The previous comment should be written in capital letters.  Retired Master Electrician is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1):

No. You have to buy an accessory ground bus.

Then you need to remove the bond that connects neutral to ground and chassis.

Cheaper panels often short you a proper ground bus and make you pay extra. That's because they expect you to be using it as a main panel where neutrals and grounds can commingle (it's not good form though).  That and their lesser quality are why they are not a good value.

I  was just looking at a Siemens main lug panel (by definition a sub panel) and was impressed to see a neutral and ground bus on each side.